# $x_0 \in \overline{Y}$ iff $f(x_0) = 0$ whenever $f \in X^∗$ with $f|_Y = 0$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed linear space, $Y$ a subspace of $X$ and $x_0 \in X$. Prove that $x_0 \in \overline{Y}$ iff $f(x_0) = 0$ whenever $f \in X^∗$ with $f|_Y = 0$.

Here $X^∗$ denotes the dual space of $X$.

I have done one direction. Struggling with the direction $f(x_0) = 0$ whenever $f \in X^∗$ with $f|_Y = 0$ implies $x_0 \in Y$. Need some hints for that.

Comment: Always better to use the full word rather than an abbreviation, for clarity.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews where does _nls_ stand for?

Comment: I assume "normed linear space," from context, but not 100% sure. @NiklasHebestreit

Comment: If $Y$ is not closed, then this is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x_0 \not\in Y$. You must define $f \in X^*$ such that $f\big|_Y = 0$ but $f(x_0) \neq 0$. Since $x_0 \neq 0$, we can consider $$Y \oplus \Bbb R x_0 \ni y + \lambda x_0 \mapsto \lambda \in \Bbb R.$$Check that this is linear and apply Hahn-Banach.

Comment: That's why we need to use Hahn-Banach to extend it, no?

Comment: Whoops, yes, missed that.